# How does Linked List function to make another linked list with different order of elements. Explanation please

Tags: c, linked-list, rotation, singly-linked-list

```
struct node* question4(struct node *list){ //list = 66, 9, 14, 52, 87, 14, 17
      struct node* a = list; //a = 66, 9, 14, 52, 87, 14, 17 pointing to head (66)
      struct node* b = list; //b = 66, 9, 14, 52, 87, 14, 17 pointing to head (66)
      struct node* c;
      if(a == NULL) return NULL; // a is not NULL it's pointing to 66
      while(a->next != NULL) // run until a points to the last element (17) 
            a = a->next;
      a->next = b; //next element of 17 points to b (which is 66). 
      c = b->next; // c points to what b is pointing to next which is 9. 
      b -> next = NULL; // next element of b is NULL(instead of 14). what happens here?
      return c;
}
```

So a is connected to b. so a's element goes like this? 
66->9->14->52->87->14->17->66->9->14->52->87->14->17

and b is just 66->9->NULL?

c is 9->14->52->87->14->17? OR 9->14->52->87->14->17->66 ? why?

I'm currently learning about linked list, thank you guys for your help!

Comment: `b->next` is basically breaking the original linked list by replacing that pointer with `NULL`. The function is then returning the remaining part of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The program shifts the head of the linked list right by one element, and loops back the original first element to the end. You have followed correctly for the most part, the last few lines work as follows:

```
a->next = b;
```

This links the original last element to the original first element, i.e., creates a link 17->66.

```
c = b->next;
```

`c` here is used to store the new head element. Since `b` was pointing to the original head, and we want the second element to be the new head, `c` points to `b`'s next element, i.e., 9.

```
b -> next = NULL;
```

The `a->next = b;` made the linked list circular, this breaks the circle, by removing the 66->9 link.

Finally, `c` is returned, so the list at the end is:

```
9->14->52->87->14->17->66
```

Comment: how does it become a circular with a single line of code: a->next = b? I understand that at the end of a (17) is connected to the head of b (66), but the code never connected the end of the b to head of the a. has it?

Comment: @AlexOh `a` and `b` are just pointers. There is actually only one list. So when `a`'s end points to `b`, it is the same as the list end pointing to its head.

Answer (score 0):

This code is used to rotate a singly-linked list to the right one node.

Let's consider this statement

```
c = b->next;
```

the pointer `b` after this declaration

```
struct node* b = list
```

points to the element with the value `66`

```
b = 66, 9, 14, 52, 87, 14, 17
```

So c points to the next element with the value 9` (b->next).

Then after this statement

```
b -> next = NULL;
```

we have

```
66, NULL, 9, 14, 52, 87, 14, 17
          ^
          |
          c
```

But after the previous code snippet

```
  while(a->next != NULL) // run until a points to the last element (17) 
        a = a->next;
  a->next = b
```

the last mode with the value 17 points to the previously first node with the value 66.

As a result you have

c =  9, 14, 52, 87, 14, 17, 66, NULL